# I want to hide some fields from the standard screen QM01/QM02/QM03 like Delivery,Delivery Item and also adding some custom fields.How to achieve it?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Hide some fields like Delivery, Delivery Item,under refernce object fields like Revision Level,Serial Number,Product Date etc from standard transaction QM01/QM02/QM03.

Also adding some custom fields to the screen to the same transaction.

Comment: Please clarify your question. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page (what did you try, only one question at a time, and so on). For general questions like that, prefer forums like the ABAP forum of SCN.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change the looks of Dynpros in Standard-TAs (especially add new fields and logic to write values to database tables) you will have to modify them. 
Some screens are customizable, but to add fields to screens of standard field-groups you will probably have to register and modify.

Comment: Hiding fields can be achieved via Transaction and Screen Variants. No need to change the standard (with a key obtained via registration at SAP support website).

Comment: You´re right, however she also wanted to include new fields. Therefore i think a screen varian won´t be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of hide them you need to have ask dev. keys for the specific objects. For new fields you have to adjust views like: VIQMEL. (append for the table of: QMEL would be the best)